# update order item after the order has been received

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My client works on markets and wants to start selling online

When he receives an order he's supposed to confirm if the item is really in stock and if he can honour the demand.

> **update >**  I already have some callbacks that check if articles are in stock or not  but...I actually need some kind of double check... ( first by callback which is done, and second manually... But I don't know how I can edit the OrderItem as the seller....

(It can happen when you work on market that you don't have time to register your sells or even some items can have be stolen... So that mess the stock)

> **update >** How can I edit the received order if an item is missing (meaning that the stock was wrong)

My Models are:

```
    Size 
        belongs_to :product

    Order
        has_many  :order_items 

    OrderItem
        belongs_to :order 
        belongs_to :product
        belongs_to :size    

    Product
        has_many :order_items
        has_many :sizes
```

OrderItem attributes are: `:id, :quantity, :product_id, :user_id, :size_id, :order_id`

Lets say an order has arrived:

```
    #here is how are orders are created

    order_1  = Order.create(
      payment: "{'stub','stripe'}", 
      created_at: 1.day.ago, 
      user_id: 1,  
      token: SecureRandom.hex(8), 
      status: 1, 
      shipping_fees: 5, 
      sub_total: [product_1.price + product_1.price].sum , 
      total: 135
    )
    order_item_1 = OrderItem.create(
      price: product_1.price, 
      order_id: order_1.id, 
      product_id: 10, 
      quantity: 1, 
      size_id: 3
    )
    order_item_2 = OrderItem.create(
      price: product_2.price, 
      order_id: order_1.id, 
      product_id: 42, 
      quantity: 2, 
      size_id: 8
    )
```

In **order_item_2** the customer needs 2 items, but my client find out that he only have one left...

My client would like something like a checklist that says for each item:

- yes it's avaiable
- woops I only have one left
- it's not available anymore

Then it would update the stock and send an email to the customer, to warn him that some item are not available etc...

What is the best way to do this?

Is it possible to manage this in the orders controller?  or shall I create an invoice controller?

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Usage of callbacks might be helpful here -- `before_create` -> run a process to check stock. For emailing you could trigger a background job/process to send an email on a callback after the client approves of the stock

Comment: And if he doesn't approve ? How can I update the order according on the available items he has?

Answer (score 1):

Order is different process for Invoice, 3 options that you mentioned you can do it in Order Controller
 if you think it's to long for one controller you can create Services with PORO system to manage the process

basically the ideal condition with full auto check for stock
if your customer choose / type Product name, the software will automatically check available stock for the product
and your customer cannot type value more than available. you can use javascript to check if the product name changed 
then it will trigger the process to check stock available and customer cannot save the order if one of Order Item ordered 
is more that available in stock

second option you can use state machine gem like [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm)

- first state, customer open the order.
- second state the order received by your client and 
  he must give approval if all order item available, if not then it's go to
- third state where the order back to customer and so on 
  until in reach last state where the order is ready to be process

usually business process after order approved it will generate another process (Delivery Order)
after Delivery Order received by customer, next process is generate Invoice for customer based from Approved and received order

Comment: Well  I already have some callbacks that check if articles are in stock or not but...as I said stock can be messed for different reasons...
It's a kind of double check that i need... One is done by the callback and the other manually by the seller

Comment: since there is some reasons that cannot be totally automatic by system, then probably you can see second option , that's probably can fit if you combined with your callback and some conditions